# Earlgrey error of NoMatchingElementException

Tags: swift, earlgrey

I am using following code in swift

```
@IBAction func letsPlay(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if(input.text == "xxx@123")
    {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {


    let storybord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")as! ViewController2
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       })
    }
```

In my Test I am using following code

```
func testValidKey() {

    EarlGreyImpl.invoked(fromFile: #file, lineNumber: #line).selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityID("inner")).perform(grey_replaceText("xxx@123"))
    var error:NSError?
    EarlGreyImpl.invoked(fromFile: #file, lineNumber: #line).selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityID("logo")).perform(grey_tap(), error:&error) 
    EarlGreyImpl.invoked(fromFile: #file, lineNumber: #line).selectElement(with: grey_accessibilityID("View2")).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())   
}
```

While testing, earlgrey should wait because it has synchronization property but its showing me error with "No matching element"

Comment: Can you be specific about what part of the interaction fails and what element is failing to match?